# Comparing univariate and bivariate models

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, univariate

I have a bivariate dataset, that is, $(\boldsymbol{y}_i, \boldsymbol{x}_i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, where $\boldsymbol{y}_i = (y_{i1}, y_{i2})$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_i = x_{i1}, \ldots, x_{ip}$ are response and regressors variables, respectively. If I use a univariate model for $y_1$ and other for $y_2$ to compare with a bivariate model, I could affirm that the bivariate model will present best performance? Using the performance metric for both approach (univariate and bivariate) given by

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
MSE_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_1 -\hat{y}_1)^2/n\\
MSE_2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_2 -\hat{y}_2)^2/n \\
\phi = MSE_1 + MSE_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In other words, I have a $\phi$ for the univariate case and other for the bivariate case.

Comment: "what happen" is too loose to ask

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd3fko25hhx30ia/mushroom_complete.txt?dl=0> The variables `id` and `species` should be deleted. The response variables are `pcw_min` and `pcw_max`.

Comment: Could you specify three models (model for $y_1$, model for $y_2$ and bivariate model)?

Comment: Normal and Student t, it is sufficient.

Comment: Normal and Student t are distributions, not models.

Comment: $\boldsymbol{y}_i = \boldsymbol{x}_i\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{e}$ considering $\boldsymbol{e}_i \sim N_2(\boldsymbol{0}, \Phi)$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_i \sim Student_2(\boldsymbol{0}, \Phi, \nu)$ (for $\nu = 3 $degrees freedom), respectively. $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is the scale matrix $\phi_{11} = 2.5, \phi_{12} = \phi_{21} = 4.5, \phi_{22} = 10$.